# Firmar xml con RSA y X509 en c#

Tags: c#, xml

yo de nuevo xD.

Me encuentro en el proceso de firmar un documento xml utilizando c#. Tengo mis archivos de la firma en una carpeta y mi xml generado. Para ello estoy usando un ejemplo de la página de Microsoft (fue el que me resultó) [Microsoft x509](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.keyinfox509data?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Hasta el momento en mi Formulario puse un botón para generar el certificado.

También comento que estoy utilizando el tipo de firmado envelope (que es el que necesito).

esta es la parte final del documento firmado que yo genero(eliminé partes de los códigos para que no fuera tan largo):

```html
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SignedInfo>
   <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
   <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
   <Reference URI="">
    <Transforms>
     <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
    </Transforms>
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <DigestValue>2gkfbuT34GapApOKNQef3whZs54=</DigestValue>
   </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue>FYO0xaRbTIHw/M6h...</SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo>
   <X509Data>
    <X509Certificate>MIIDNjCCAh6gAwIBAgIQNozDOzKInKBAbJ67yETfnjANBgkqhk.....</X509Certificate>
   </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
 </Signature>
```

Se ve bien, pero viendo un documento de ejemplo firmado que me entregaron me esta faltando información:

Pongo un ejemplo:

```html
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
     <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
     <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
     <Reference URI="#Documento101">
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
      <DigestValue>3JUP4fsboOzM3v...</DigestValue>
     </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>KfDaAuizrGD6p5i0pwN...</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
     <KeyValue>
      <RSAKeyValue>
       <Modulus>x8uFiN6dlSJHcmDBaSJQB8Eh+SfSRrwdvJITx6F7RlTsiAru8VQ+O6RMgMYH8vVsx9X86mcBSiJUsd+z2bcJHdTkOsgthUG7Ke00wMchASb3gYLXsIWgS0/...</Modulus>
       <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
      </RSAKeyValue>
     </KeyValue>
     <X509Data>
      <X509Certificate>MIIHLjCCBhagAwIBAgIKMOyn8gA...</X509Certificate>
     </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
   </Signature>
```

Y como se ve me está faltando la llave RSAKeyValue.

Mi consulta es, acorde a este ejemplo que estoy tomando de Microsoft. ¿qué es lo que me está faltando agregar para generar la RSAKeyValue?

Porque en la pagina encontré cómo se genera la [RSAKeyValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.rsakeyvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) pero necesito lograr que me genere la RSA y la X509 al apretar un solo botón de mi aplicación. Quizás sea algo de orden, primero genero la RSA y después le agrego el certificado X509 pero ando un poco perdido.

Si se necesita algo del código que tengo me avisan y lo pongo.

Gracias

Comment: En el objeto Signature  puedes agregarle una propiedad mas y agregarle el  elemento que te hace falta, revisa el codigo e identifica como lo generas.

Comment: vendría a ser esta linea? doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true)); . porque acá agrego al documento la firma digital

Comment: primero entiende el codigo que estas usando,pues debes identificar donde esta ese elemento algo asi como   string str = RSA.ToXmlString(true);  // para agregar rsa info al xml

Comment: creo que ya entendí, para generar ya sea la firma como rsa o x509 las primeras 10  líneas son lo mismo, generar documento. el código que tengo, lo pongo acá o como una respuesta a mi pregunta? es para ver si voy bien

Comment: primero haz una prueba y si todo va bien agrega tu respuesta igual y le sirve a alguien mas.

Comment: Y casi lo tengo listo, mi duda es como agrego un solo elemento que contenga estas dos firmas, porque tengo:

doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignatureRSA, true));
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

peor me genera dos campos signature con la info y necesito una.

doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignatureRSA, true), doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true)); 

eso no funciona

Comment: concatenar estos dos elementos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, con la ayuda de **Miguel Zarate**, muchas gracias por la guía.
Pude sacar el tema de la firma, espero que a alguien que también esté en este mismo dilema le pueda servir.

Este programa que estoy haciendo genera un documento xml y después tengo otro botón que es para firmar el documento, esta firma es una que yo generé en el pc que la estoy usando de prueba.

El código del botón es:

```html
private void btn_Firmax509_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // ubicación de mi certificado
            string Certificate = "C:/LocalMachine/my/tstCert.cer";

            try
            {
                // Generate a signing key.
                RSACryptoServiceProvider Key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

                SignXmlFile(path, path3, Key, Certificate);
            }
            catch (CryptographicException i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.Message);
            }

        }
```

En este declaro la ubicación de mi certificado, genero una llave y le envío 4 variables a la función que va a firmar.

El **path** hace referencia a dónde tengo el archivo original NO firmado, el **path3** es la ruta de donde voy a dejar el archivo xml firmado, se envía la llave y la ubicación del certificado.

La función que firma:

```html
public static void SignXmlFile(string FileName, string SignedFileName, RSA Key, string Certificate)
        {
            // --------- FIRMADO X509 ----------------
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();       // Create a new XML document.
            doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;            // formateo el documento para que ignore los espacios
            doc.Load(new XmlTextReader(FileName));     // recargo el archivo
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);  // creo el objto del documento como firmado?
            signedXml.SigningKey = Key;        // a este documento firmado le agrego la llave
            Reference reference = new Reference();      // creo una referencia para firmar
            reference.Uri = "";
            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();  // Creo En sobre para el XML -> env
            reference.AddTransform(env);            //a esta referencia le agrego una transformación de tipo envelope
            signedXml.AddReference(reference);      // y ahora esta referencia se la asigno al documento firmado

            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();        // Ahora tengo que crear un objeto para firmar

            keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((RSA)Key)); //agrego la firma RSA

            X509Certificate MSCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(Certificate);   // Descargamos el certificado
            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(MSCert));


            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
            signedXml.ComputeSignature();
            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignatureRSA = signedXml.GetXml(); //elemento con la firma RSA y X509


            // Agrego al documento un hijo con las llaves
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignatureRSA, true));
                       
            if (doc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
            {
                doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild);
            }

            //guardo el documento
            XmlTextWriter xmltw = new XmlTextWriter(SignedFileName, new UTF8Encoding(false));
            doc.WriteTo(xmltw);
            xmltw.Close();
        }
```